# C++: I'm trying to create a calculator, but every time I try to divide, substract, or multiply, the calculator only keeps adding

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a calculator, but every time I try to divide, substract, or multiply, the calculator only keeps adding. I'm dutch btw, so

1. Add,
2. Substract,
3. Multiply,
4. Divide

Antwoord = answer

Bewerking = operator

Pls help! It's for a school assignment.

### Code below

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    cout << "Calculator [v.1.0]" << endl;
    cout << "(c) 2021 <Chayenne van der Erf>" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Kies een bewerking en druk op Enter:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Optellen              2. Aftrekken" << endl;
    cout << "3. Vermenigvuldigen      4. Delen" <<endl;
    cout << "5. Kwadraat              6. Worteltrekken" <<endl;
    cout << "7. Reciproke             8. Logarithme" <<endl;
    cout << "0. Exit" << endl << endl;

    int Bewerking;
    cout << "Bewerking: ";
    cin >> Bewerking;

    cout << "" << endl;

    switch (Bewerking) {
    case 1:
     cout << "+";
        break;
    case 2:
    cout << "-";
        break;
    case 3:
    cout << "*";
        break;
    case 4:
     cout << "/";
        break;

    default: "Invalid Number";
    }

    cout << "" << endl << endl;
    float A, B;

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> B;
    float antwoord;
     if (Bewerking = '+') {antwoord = A + B;}
        else if (Bewerking = '-' ) {antwoord = A - B;}
        else if (Bewerking = '*') {antwoord = A * B;}
        else if (Bewerking = '/') {antwoord = A / B;}

    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "= " << antwoord << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if (Bewerking = '+') {antwoord = A + B;}` always returns true, since you assign `Bewerking = '+'` not compare `Bewerking == '+'`.

You need to change all the conditions to have the following form:

```
if (Bewerking == '+');
```

Yet, clearing this bug still gives invalid results.

This is because in `cin >> Bewerking;` user supplies a **number**, while the check we make is `if (Bewerking == '+')`, where we look for a **character**. So, in an none of the `if` clauses will be really true, thus the `antwoord` will remain **uninitialized**, leading to bizarre output at the end.

You just have to stick to the numbers then:

```
double antwoord = 0; // Better supply a default value 
if (Bewerking == 1) antwoord = A + B;
if (Bewerking == 2) antwoord = A - B;
if (Bewerking == 3) antwoord = A * B;
if (Bewerking == 4) antwoord = A / B;
// If none is true, the antwoord defaults to 0
```

*Or you can make `Bewerking` a `char` and build all the logic around that.*

Comment: I tried working with compare, but then the answer I would get is nonsensical, like 5 + 5 = 8900000 or something like that. It happens with every operator I use. Is there any reason why that could be?

Comment: @ChayennevanderErf check the latest edit.

Comment: @ChayennevanderErf you're welcome! Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you consider one as such.

Comment: `You just have to stick to the numbers` Why not declare `char Bewerking;`?

Comment: @S.M. yeah, one way or another! The interface would need to be changed then (character case). Path of least resistance. But will point out the alternative approach in the answer. Thanks!